# Get the name of the input variable in a function

Tags: javascript, node.js, debugging, ecmascript-6, binary-tree

This appears to be a difficult question to answer.  Given a function such as the one displayed how would you get the name of the input variable for debugging purposes.  i.e.) root -> root.left -> root.right -> root.left.right -> etc... 
or i.e.) tree -> tree.left -> tree.right -> tree.left.right -> etc...

```
function TreeNode(val) {
    this.val = val;
    this.left = this.right = null;
}
var sum = function(root) {
    console.log(root);
    if(root === null) return 0;
    return root.val + sum(root.left) + sum(root.right);
}

let tree = new TreeNode(1);
tree.left = new TreeNode(2);
tree.right = new TreeNode(3);
tree.left.right = new TreeNode(4);
let x = sum(tree);
console.log(x);
```

Basically, I want to console.log() the name of the variable rather than root in the sum function.

Comment: So you want to log `"tree"`? Or am I understanding it incorrectly?

Comment: That's a good question.  I suppose either tree or root.  Then, I would like to log either tree.left or root.left etc...

Comment: You can't.  When your `sum` function is called, it is passed a value.  That value is a pointer to an object and there is no connection at all to the variable that the pointer came from.  If you did `let x = y = tree;` and then did `sum(x)` and `sum(y)`, there would be no difference at all in the two calls to `sum()`.  They were passed the exact same value (a pointer to the `tree` object) and there is no reference at all to `x` or `y`.

Comment: If it's for debugging purposes while it's running, just use a debugger and put a breakpoint in the function. Or add a `debugger` statement (it's a manual debug point). At any rate, you'll be able to step back in the call chain to see how the function was called. If you want to see it in some sort of log, then I don't think it's possible.

Answer (score 1):

> Basically, I want to console.log() the name of the variable rather than root in the sum function.

You can't.  When your `sum` function is called, it is passed a value.  That value is a pointer to an object and there is no connection at all to the variable that the pointer came from.  If you did this:

```
let tree = new TreeNode(1);
let x = y = tree;
sum(x);
sum(y);
```

there would be no difference at all in the two calls to `sum()`.  They were each passed the exact same value (a pointer to a `TreeNode` object) and there is no reference at all to `x` or `y` or `tree` in the `sum()` function.

If you want extra info (like the name of a variable) for debugging reasons and/or logging, then you may have to pass that extra name into the function so you can log it.

Answer (score 0):

You can change the `sum` function for debugging purposes:

```
function sum(root, path) {
  if(!path) {
    path = 'root';
  }
  console.log(path);
  if(root === null) return 0;
  return root.val + sum(root.left, path+'.left') + sum(root.right, path+'.right'); 
}
```